# "./OpenGrok index" failed

Tags: java, deployment, indexing, opengrok

I am trying to implement OpenGrok to search some source tree. There was no error when running "./OpenGrok deploy", but afterwards when I ran "./OpenGrok index", there jumped lots of similar errors which I will attached below. The full source tree I want to search is a very hug project, around 20G big, and the weird thing is that, I can successfully run "./OpenGrok index" if the source code is a small size one. So I am not sure is there any file number limit or size limit that OpenGrok follows, if there is, where can I make changes? Or it is because some other reason.

Thanks!

```
11:38:02 SEVERE: Failed to read from process: cvs
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cvs" (in directory "/home/pss/Tools/OpenGrok/src/REL_6_2_2_S6/feature/ipsec/server"): error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1041)
        at org.opensolaris.opengrok.util.Executor.exec(Executor.java:131)
        at org.opensolaris.opengrok.history.CVSHistoryParser.parse(CVSHistoryParser.java:163)
        at org.opensolaris.opengrok.history.CVSRepository.getHistory(CVSRepository.java:216)
        at org.opensolaris.opengrok.history.FileHistoryCache.get(FileHistoryCache.java:227)
        at org.opensolaris.opengrok.history.HistoryGuru.getHistory(HistoryGuru.java:212)
        at org.opensolaris.opengrok.history.HistoryGuru.getHistoryReader(HistoryGuru.java:175)
        at org.opensolaris.opengrok.analysis.AnalyzerGuru.populateDocument(AnalyzerGuru.java:257)
        at org.opensolaris.opengrok.index.IndexDatabase.addFile(IndexDatabase.java:637)
        at org.opensolaris.opengrok.index.IndexDatabase.indexDown(IndexDatabase.java:888)
        at org.opensolaris.opengrok.index.IndexDatabase.indexDown(IndexDatabase.java:858)
        at org.opensolaris.opengrok.index.IndexDatabase.indexDown(IndexDatabase.java:858)
        at org.opensolaris.opengrok.index.IndexDatabase.update(IndexDatabase.java:391)
        at org.opensolaris.opengrok.index.IndexDatabase$1.run(IndexDatabase.java:171)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:135)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1022)
        ... 19 more
11:38:02 WARNING: Non-zero exit status -1 from command [cvs, log, test_ike.c] in directory /home/pss/Tools/OpenGrok/src/REL_6_2_2_S6/feature/ipsec/server
11:38:02 WARNING: An error occurred while reading history:
org.opensolaris.opengrok.history.HistoryException: Failed to get history for: "/home/pss/Tools/OpenGrok/src/REL_6_2_2_S6/feature/ipsec/server/test_ike.c" Exit code: -1
        at org.opensolaris.opengrok.history.CVSHistoryParser.parse(CVSHistoryParser.java:166)
        at org.opensolaris.opengrok.history.CVSRepository.getHistory(CVSRepository.java:216)
        at org.opensolaris.opengrok.history.FileHistoryCache.get(FileHistoryCache.java:227)
        at org.opensolaris.opengrok.history.HistoryGuru.getHistory(HistoryGuru.java:212)
        at org.opensolaris.opengrok.history.HistoryGuru.getHistoryReader(HistoryGuru.java:175)
        at org.opensolaris.opengrok.analysis.AnalyzerGuru.populateDocument(AnalyzerGuru.java:257)
        at org.opensolaris.opengrok.index.IndexDatabase.addFile(IndexDatabase.java:637)
        at org.opensolaris.opengrok.index.IndexDatabase.indexDown(IndexDatabase.java:888)
        at org.opensolaris.opengrok.index.IndexDatabase.indexDown(IndexDatabase.java:858)
        at org.opensolaris.opengrok.index.IndexDatabase.indexDown(IndexDatabase.java:858)
        at org.opensolaris.opengrok.index.IndexDatabase.update(IndexDatabase.java:391)
        at org.opensolaris.opengrok.index.IndexDatabase$1.run(IndexDatabase.java:171)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Comment: Why you need CVS. I have implemented opengrok and its working fine.I am check out the code from SVN browse from browser using OpenGrok.

Answer (score 0):

Do you Do the `openGrok index` while checking out the code , and from error code. Have you put `cvs` to your env path